# Headless application with BlackBerry WebWorks

Tags: cordova, blackberry-webworks

I created a Blackberry Webworks application with Eclipse (using Phonegap).
I need this application to run in background when the device starts (to send requests every 10 minutes).

I read that this is possible with Blackberry native code. But is there a way to do that with Blackberry Webworks (Blackberry OS 10.2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible with BlackBerry WebWorks 2.1.

A new command, create-headless, has been introduced to the CLI of the BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK. This command allows you to create a WebWorks app with a headless service.

You have just to follow this tutorial :

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/v2_1/creating_a_ww_app_with_headless_app.html